# Getting javascript click to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that this is a really simple question but I can't see why it does not work. clicking on the div causes the alert but neither of the submits do. What am I doing that is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        alert("Test 1 was clicked.");
    });

    $(".submit").on('click', function(){
        alert("Test 2 was clicked.");
    });

    $("#test").click(function(){
        alert("Test 3 was clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type='submit' value='Click'>
<div id='test'>Click</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't have the element with class `.submit` on the page

Comment: There is no element with the class `submit`. You can use `$("[type='submit']")`

Comment: `$(".submit")` selects elements with the *class* of submit, not the type or name. Ex: `<input type='submit' value='Click' class="submit">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why your code is not working?**

There is no element with the class`.submit`. So `click` will not work.

**Solution**

Use a proper selector like `$("[type='submit']")` or add the class `submit` to the element.

**Working Demo**

```js
$("[type='submit']").click(function() {
  alert("Test 1 was clicked.");
});

$("[type='submit']").on('click', function() {
  alert("Test 2 was clicked.");
});

$("#test").click(function() {
  alert("Test 3 was clicked.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='submit' value='Click'>
<div id='test'>Click</div>
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you so much. I had been looking at so many answers and all simply refer to .submit.

Comment: @RGriffiths    Always glad to help :)

Comment: Interestingly it is only the Click version that works on my site. If I use the on('click' .... it never fires. I think I understand the purpose of the On but would having many submit buttons on the page cause an issue using that method?

Comment: Yes.. it will cause issues. Then you have to give specific ID for submit button

Comment: Perfect. All working now - much appreciate your help. Superb!